# Screen Capture under Ubuntu (Wine)

Tags: c#, ubuntu, screenshot, ubuntu-14.04, wine

I'm trying to get a screen capture. Under Windows works like a charm.

Windows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umwF4.jpg

But, under Ubuntu (14.04 LTS, using Wine) isn't working propely.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KARW.jpg

I know it's a Wine problem that doesn't wrap all the functions correctly. But, is there any other way to get a screen capture I could try that works under Ubuntu/Windows? Thanks.

My actual code:

```
int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight)){
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)){
        g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated Wine to 1.7.5 (Beta version) and now it's working like a charm!